# height of parent not changing by child margins

Tags: html, css

I have a very small code:

```css
.parent{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.child{
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
}
.a1{
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
  <head>         
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child a1"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

the height of .parent is showing only 220px, but if we calculate as per child's height+margin it should be 280. I am unable to understand

Jsfiddle is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3oztabk8/)

Comment: where are you getting 220px???

Comment: Please see in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

That's the phenomenon know as "collapsing margins" (google it): margins of parent and child are merged, only the larger one of them is applied to the parent.

If necessary, you can avoid that by adding a tiny `padding` to the parent (1px):

```css
body {
  background: #ddd;
}

.parent {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.a1 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child a1"></div>
</div>
```

Addition: 
The same applies to the `body` element, which has a default margin (5px in most browsers), which is the grey area you see in my previous snippet. To avoid that, reset the `margin` for `html` and `body`.

And as @TEmani Afif mentioned in the comments, margin collapsing also applies *between*  sibling elements. So in the following snippet (where I reset the body margin), you see 20px margin not only around both elements, but the margin between the two elements isn't 2 x 20px (as one could believe), but due to collapsing margins only 1 x 20px;

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #ddd;
}

.parent {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #fff;
}

.child {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: red;
}

.a1 {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child a1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's also margin-collapsing between both childs  .. parent has 0 margin ... then we have margin-collapsing with the body

Answer (score -1):

You can solve it by adding `border: 1px solid transparent;` or you can also give padding like `padding:0.5px;`.

Comment: it's also margin-collapsing between both childs .. parent has 0 margin ... then we have margin-collapsing with the body